# How to display adview on other view(custom view) in android

Tags: android, custom-view, adview

How to display adview on other view(custom view) in android ?
I need to play ads on custom view.
This is the xml I am using.

```
<RelativeLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnmenu"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:text="Menu"
android:typeface="sans"
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="@drawable/white"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>
</Button>

<com.google.ads.AdView 
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXX"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

<view
class="com.android.MainScreen" 
android:id="@+id/note"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/btnmenu"
android:padding="10dip"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fadingEdge="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it doing now? What is the problem that you're having?

Comment: Currently Ad is not getting displayed with above xml. I want to display Ads on my custom view and not in between menu button and custom view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your AdView below your custom view in the XML file. It may be drawing the custom view on top of the AdView. You'll also want to set the AdView's position below the button like you are doing with your custom view with `android:layout_below="@+id/btnmenu"`.

```
<view
class="com.android.MainScreen" 
android:id="@+id/note"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/btnmenu"
android:padding="10dip"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fadingEdge="vertical" />

<com.google.ads.AdView 
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/btnmenu"
ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXX"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

it's very help to u....`

```
AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] {
                //AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR // Android emulator
                "ENTER_DEVICE_ID_HERE", // Device ID of the device you want to test on
                } );

        AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
        adView.requestFreshAd();
      `
```

Comment: My problem is not with Ad display. I want to display Ad on my custom view.